# Blazor insists taking wrong initial namespace

Tags: c#, namespaces, blazor

I have weird problem in Blazor (in .cs files works just fine)
there are two different namespaces:

1. Sports.Entities.Metadata.*
2. Vision.Sports.Entities.Metadata.*

for some reason all the razor files insists that Sports must be Vision.Sports although i need the first namespace described, i find  no explanation to this behavior and no way using the first namespace inside razor files, in the cs file on the other hand no such problem.

any idea what causes this behavior?

[image]

[![file path structure][2]][2]

file path structure
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/bGsB6.png

Comment: Show us the full file path structure in the Solution Explorer

Comment: Hmm, that's pretty funky, I don't use blazor but that doesn't look like it should happen. I suggest having a quick look over the namespace stuff here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/?view=aspnetcore-5.0#namespaces-1

Comment: added file path structure. there's nothing out of the ordinary

Answer (score 0):

Solved by merging the 2 namespaces (removed the Vision prefix in 2 classes that had it), i think there is an issue with Blazor there, for some reason it mixes up namespaces when there is a prefix to one in two different namespaces.